# JEE application in Docker accessing local DB port

Tags: database, docker

I am trying to deploy a JEE application in Docker container. The application requires embedded apache derby on port 1527. It works fine when run in regular dev environment. However, when I run inside a Docker container, the connection on port 1527 is refused.

Things to note, I am using 'default' db connection. That means the application is trying to access the database on localhost:1527. Following is the error message:

> java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused (Connection refused).

I am wondering what does localhost mean within a Docker container, the host server or the container?

Any suggestions to fix it?

Comment: Localhost in a container is the container itself, outside the container if the process runs inside a Docker container. Have you exposed the 1527 port? Have you got a local DB? Or are you linking it to a DB?

Comment: Post your compose file and are your running apache derby in the another container or trying to re-use the one from your host?